# Tag search includes [sass] on search for [*css]

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, tag-search

When searching for [[*css]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*css), the [sass](/questions/tagged/sass) tag is incorrectly returned:

[image: Image of a tag search grouping including the tag in question]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the [sass](/questions/tagged/sass) tag also has the tag [scss](/questions/tagged/scss) listed as a synonym of it, which *does* match the criteria `*css` and gets remapped back to its master tag when listed anywhere.

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks! I'll accept shortly.