# Is this a hidden feature or a bug?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tags, title

If you try to write `[tag]` at the beginning of a title, you'll see this error:

[image]

But I figured out, writing  `[tag]` overcomes the error, and the space is stripped on submit anyway.

**I don't want this fixed**, because it allows me to write a title like: [Tag search includes [sass] on search for [*css]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180859/sass-is-matched-on-search-for-css)

But I'm curious: is it a hidden feature or a bug? It isn't listed at [Hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow)

<sup>Side note: this error should probably be disabled on Meta sites to allow for titles about tags.</sup>

Comment: Pretty sure this counts as a bug, not a hidden feature. We don't really design for backdoors in our title checks and so this is more of an oversight than anything. Though at the very least I should look into a nicer title for you so that this isn't even a problem.

Comment: It's a hidden feature bug!

Comment: It's a new feature, is it not? If so, this should be [status-completed]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84802/warn-users-before-posting-if-they-have-a-tag-at-the-start-of-their-title

Comment: @Richard The syntax talked about here is explicitly pointed out in Jeff's answer to that linked question as being blocked from back then. The parent request there, however, asks about a different syntax that is not implemented and so it isn't status completed.

Comment: Eeeek! Kill it with fire! Pseudo-tags are evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this. If you need to quote a tag at the beginning of a title, use ...quotes :-)

E.g.

> "[sass]" is matched on search for "[*css]"

---

Fix will be out in `rev 1909` (meta) and `rev. 1340` (network)